# How to use react routing with IPFS

Tags: react-router, ipfs

I'm using react routing for my site but on IPFS it doesn't work it's looking for a path that doesn't exist

```
<Nav className="">
 <Nav.Link className="custom-link" to="/home" eventKey="1" href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
 <Nav.Link  to="/dex" eventKey="2" href="/dex">DEX</Nav.Link>
 <Nav.Link  to="/defi" eventKey="3" >DEFI</Nav.Link>
 <Nav.Link  to="/nft" eventKey="3" >NFT</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

The Route

```
import {BrowserRouter,Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch className ="switch">
    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/dex" component={Dex} />
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Once deployed on IPFS if I click on a link I get;

```
ipfs resolve -r /ipfs/bafybeifwqscmvkuffygd7tqioy6fusuh3q7y4xlq7d7bfhkbkrsftcruoy/dex: no link named "dex" under bafybeifwqscmvkuffygd7tqioy6fusuh3q7y4xlq7d7bfhkbkrsftcruoy
```

How can I get my route to work on IPFS?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter